# How do I create this function correctly?

Tags: python

I have defined a function string_adder that receives two arguments and returns a concatenated version of both arguments.

```
def string_adder(a,b):
    bac = a + " " + b
    return bac

string_adder("boy","girl")
print (string_adder)
```

However, when I run the code, I get this error message:

> <function string_adder at 0x10cf5bb90>

Any advice on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: `print(string_adder("boy","girl"))` - currently you are printing the function itself, not the result of calling it.

Comment: Or with two lines: `result = string_adder("boy", "girl")` and the next line `print(result)`. You need to assign the result of your function to a variable, before you can use it further.

Comment: I would suggest going through a basic course in Python before asking such a question. You actually print the function instance and not the function call.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

On the line `string_adder("boy","girl")` you call the function but don't do anything with what it returns. You need to change it to `string_adder = string_adder("boy","girl")`, probably with a different variable name for ease of reading. You'd need to change the print line in that case too.

Comment: Not just for ease of reading but for not shadowing / overwriting the original function

Answer (score 0):

As you said *"and returns a"*, so you need to use what is returned, because `print (string_adder)` print the method's object

```
result = string_adder("boy", "girl")
print(result)  # boy girl

print(string_adder("boy", "girl"))  # boy girl
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def string_adder(a, b):
    return a + " " + b


a = string_adder("boy", "girl")
print(a)
```

You were printing the function.